# how to use gcloud command in docker build image with credentials

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, gcloud, google-cloud-sdk

I have a project in which I need to use gcloud commands, I need to build with the proper credentials, seems gcloud commands don't use the variable GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS, so I set the auth in RUN step in docker

```
FROM google/cloud-sdk
COPY . usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app 
RUN gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file=/usr/src/app/credentials.json
```

but when I build the image and enter to the container I have no access to gcloud commands, lets say

`gcloud projects list`

I have the next answer

WARNING: Could not open the configuration file: [/root/.config/gcloud/configurations/config_default].
ERROR: (gcloud.projects.list) You do not currently have an active account selected.

credentials are inside the container because if I do manually I can run the next command and everything works well.

`gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file=/usr/src/app/credentials.json`

how can add the credentials to exist by default in build?, does the RUN step may not take effect when building the image.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct, `gcloud` does not check `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS`.

I think you're not using the Google-approved container image: [Google Cloud SDK Docker](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-sdk-docker)

See [Usage](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-sdk-docker#usage) for a good way to mount service account credentials into the container.